# ¿Cómo ejecutar aplicación hecha en google endpoint de manera local local?

Tags: google-app-engine

Buen dia,

Estoy empezando a desarrollar aplicacion en Google Endpoints con JAVA, al momento de ingresar al link [localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer](http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer),me aparece el siguiente error:

> The API you are exploring is hosted over HTTP, which can cause
>   problems. Learn how to use Explorer with a local HTTP API.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver ese problema necesitas iniciar una sesión de chrome con algunas banderas especiales:

```
[path-to-Chrome] --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:port
```

Un ejemplo mas concreto:

```
 /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --user-data-dir=test --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://localhost:8080
```

Esto pasa porque existe contenido mesclado, el explorador de las APIs se carga con HTTPS pero tu API corre sobre HTTP.